# Power set of a set with an empty set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

When a set has an empty set as an element, e.g.$ \{\emptyset, a, b \}$. What is the powerset?

Is it:  $$ \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\emptyset, a\} \{\emptyset, b\}, \{a, b\}, \{\emptyset, a, b\}\}$$

Or

$$ \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\emptyset, a\} \{\emptyset, b\}, \{a, b\}, \{\emptyset, a, b\}\}$$

Or 
$$ \{ \{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\emptyset, a\} \{\emptyset, b\}, \{a, b\}, \{\emptyset, a, b\}\}$$

The confusion arises for me because, the powerset of every non-empty set has an empty set. Well the original set already has the empty set. So we don't need a subset with an empty set.

Somehow, the first one seems correct. Yet, I can't seem to accept it.

Comment: The first one: $\;\emptyset\;$ **is one** of the elements of the given set, *besides* being a subset of it.

Comment: Let $c$ denote $\varnothing$. What is the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$? Now write $\varnothing$ instead of $c$ again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is correct.

This is because $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are different. The first is an empty set whereas the second is a set whose *only element* is the empty set.

Both are subsets of the given set. This is because the $\emptyset$ is the subset of every set, and as it happens to be an element of the given set, the set containing it as its element is also its subset.

Answer (score 3):

If a set $A$ is such that $\emptyset\in A$, its power set must *necessarily* contain these two sets:

- $\emptyset$ (like all other power sets), corresponding to selecting nothing from $A$ (not even $\emptyset$, which is *something*)
- $\{\emptyset\}$, corresponding to selecting $\emptyset$ only

Therefore only the first of your proposed answers is correct, as you think.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestions differ by having $\emptyset$ and/or $\{\emptyset\}$ included or not.

- We have $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(X)$ because $\emptyset\subseteq X$ (which would hold for any other $X$ as well)
- We have $\{\emptyset\}\in\mathcal P(X)$ because $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq X$ (which is the case because $\emptyset\in X$ in this specific problem)

Therefore, your first variant is correct (and the other two are incorrect because $\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$).

Comment: Your second bullet is strangely phrased to me; we have $\{\emptyset\}\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ simply because $\emptyset\in X$ in this specific problem. The fact that $\emptyset\subseteq X$, which is true for every set $X$, has nothing to do with it?